# Multiple output classification with TensorFLow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm working with Python 3.6.9 and TensorFlow 2.3.

I'm working on a classifier where the expected output is an array of classes one hot encoded. Each row represents one category between 4:

```
[ [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,1,0],
  ...
  [0,1,0,0] ]
```

I trained the network on a trivial problem. To do so, I flatten the array to fit the last layer of my network which is described here:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4*length, activation='linear'),
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It's not working properly, since it can't deal with my multiple outputs and does not classify `Length` classes, but try to find one class in `length*4` output.

To summarize, the expected output is a `[Length,4]` array, and my network optimize a `[Length*4]` vector. I already read many blogs and SO questions, but I can't figure out how to deal with my multiple output.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is the input to the network, and what is the output you want? Does `Length` is the batch size?

Comment: The input of the network is a string for which I would like to classify each character in one class (between 4 classes). The output is a class for each character. Length is not the batch size, length is the number of characters in the string. All the string in my dataset have the same length. If the strings have 10 characters, the expected output is a `[10,4]' array where each row represents a one hot encoded classification.